# Definite integral of inverse function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Task is: 
$$\int_{\sqrt(\pi/6)}^{\sqrt(\pi/3)}\sin(x^2)dx + \int_{1/2}^{\sqrt{3}/2}\sqrt{\arcsin x}dx$$

If we say, that $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$, and $a = \sqrt(\pi/6)$, $b= \sqrt(\pi/3)$ then we have:

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)dx$$

But I really don't know what to do with this knowledge.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You probably wanted to write something like $\sqrt{\pi/6}$ `$\sqrt{\pi/6}$`. You can also write $\sqrt{\frac\pi6}$ `$\sqrt{\frac\pi6}$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second form is quite suggestive. You really have two options here:

1. **Draw a picture:** plot $x$ against $f(x)$, shade the areas corresponding to the integrals (hint: look up the vertical axis to find the $f^{-1}$ area), and then become appalled when you realise how trivial the picture makes it.
2. **Do algebra:** substitute in the second integral ($u=f^{-1}(x)$), and integrate by parts.

Comment: Oh, so easy, silly me. Thank you, I've understood 1st method, but I haven't understood 2nd. I've ended with $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx + f^{-1}(f(b))*b-f^{-1}(f(a))*a - \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}\frac{x}{f'(x)}dx$

Comment: The second integral has $x=f(u)$, so the integrand is $f^{-1}(f(u))=u$, the limits become $a$ and $b$, and the measure transforms by $dx =f'(u) \, du$, so you have $ \int_a^b u f'(u) \, du$.